# How can I set the default value for a radio button on load of document?

Tags: jquery

I need to set default value for radio button on load of document. I tried this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":radio[name='sectionRules']").val(1);
});
```

but it is not working. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(":radio[name='sectionRules'][value='1']").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

… although I don't understand why you are waiting for the whole DOM to load and then setting it with JS instead of just setting the checked attribute in the HTML in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(":radio[name='sectionRules']").attr('checked', true);
```